# Why setState interrupt componentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

I have this component (simplified version):

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            data: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(this.props.time && this.props.time !== prevProps.time){
           this.setState({
             isLoading: true
           })
           fetch(...).then(data => {
             this.setState({
               data: data
               isLoading:false
             }
        }
    }
    render(){
      {isLoading, data} = this.state;
      return (isLoading ? /*show spinner*/ : /* show data*/);
    }

}
```

This component works: it shows a spinner while fetching data, then it shows the data.

I'm trying to test it using jest and enzyme:

```
test('Mounted correctly', async() => {
   let myComponent = mount(<MyComponent time='01-01-18'/>);
   myComponent.setProps({time: '02-01-18'}); //necessary to call componentDidUpdate
   expect(myComponent.state()).toMatchSnapshot();
}
```

From my knowledge, in order to call `componentDidUpdate` **you have to** call `setPros` ([link](https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913)). However, following the debugger, the call end when hitting:

```
       this.setState({
         isLoading: true
       })
```

Which is kinda of expected, the problem is that the snapshot is:

```
Object {
  "isLoading": true
  "data": {}
}
```

Which is, of course, something that I don't want. How can I solve this?

**UPDATE: I found a(n ugly) solution!**

The problem is that what we want to test is this `setState` is completed:

```
         this.setState({
           data: data
           isLoading:false
         }
```

Now, this doesn't happen even by setting `await myComponent.setProps({time: '02-01-18'});` (as suggested in one of the answers), because it doesn't wait for the new asynchronous call created by the `setState` described above.

The only solution that I found is to pass a callback function to `props` and call it after `setState` is completed. The callback function contains the `expect` that we want!

So this is the final result:

```
test('Mounted correctly', async() => {
   let myComponent = mount(<MyComponent time='01-01-18'/>);
   const callBackAfterLastSetStateIsCompleted = () => {
      expect(topAsins.state()).toMatchSnapshot();
   }
   myComponent.setProps({time: '02-01-18', testCallBack: callBackAfterLastSetStateIsCompleted}); //necessary to call componentDidUpdate
   expect(myComponent.state()).toMatchSnapshot();
}
```

And modify the component code as:

```
         this.setState({
           data: data
           isLoading:false
         },this.props.testCallBack);
```

However, as you can see, I'm modifying a component in production only for testing purpose, which is something *very* ugly.

**Now, my question is**: how can I solve this?

Comment: You would have to wait for `fetch` to actually complete. Note that `fetch` is asynchronous. See https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html

Comment: That could be probably because while you're doing `setState()`, the component re-renders and `fetch` runs before component mounts again during which you're again doing `setState()`, which could cause this issue. Set initial state `isLoading: true` which could solve your issue, as you'll not have to `setState()` just before fetch.

Comment: as an aside, you probably want to be doing this in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: @Hamms you mean the spin loader or what? Can you tell me more?

Comment: Please, look at the updated question!

Comment: Yeah, all the stuff that's in `componentDidUpdate` right now. As your code currently stands, every time your component updates with a new time, you kick off a fetch and also set the `isLoading` state to true; that `setState` will actually cause _another_ update, so you'll be rendering twice for every time change. If you instead do this in `componentWillReceiveProps`, both the state update and the prop update will happen on the same render

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do here to test is make use of `async/await` like

```
test('Mounted correctly', async () => {
   let myComponent = mount(<MyComponent time='01-01-18'/>);
   await myComponent.setProps({time: '02-01-18'}); //necessary to call componentDidUpdate, await used to wait for async action in componentDidUpdate
   expect(myComponent.state()).toMatchSnapshot();
}
```

Comment: Ok, now the debugger follows goes over the `setState` of my question, but when it hits the `expect` the state is still not updated :(